# NSDateFormatter gives me wrong date when i choose IST from phone settings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, nsdateformatter

This code perfectly works on my simulator but am facing problem when i run it on my device and change the timezone to IST (Indian Standard Time)

Runnable code:

```
    var zones = ["Asia/Calcutta","Asia/Hong_Kong"]
    for eachtimeZone in zones{
    println(eachtimeZone)
    var nTZ:NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone(name: eachtimeZone)!

    var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: nTZ.abbreviation!)

    println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
    println(NSDate())

    }
```

Output when i use a simulator:

```
Asia/Calcutta
06:11 AM
2014-10-29 00:41:36 +0000
Asia/Hong_Kong
08:41 AM
2014-10-29 00:41:36 +0000
```

Output when i set my time manually to IST

```
Asia/Calcutta
06:11 AM
2014-10-29 00:41:36 +0000
Asia/Hong_Kong
06:11 AM
2014-10-29 00:41:36 +0000
```

Setting when not working on phone:
[image]

What is wrong in this code?

Used Xcode 6/IOS8/Iphone 5S

NB: Kolkata = Calcutta. Same place.

```
Update1:
```

Scenerio: Device time has been set to Indian Standard time (IST) by going to setting.
I am then trying to execute the above code which print Hong Kong Standard time(HKT) and IST. 
HKT displayed by the code is wrong.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to interpret what your various conditions are in the above tests.

Comment: Thats the only code am running in my View Controller.If you just put this code in ViewDidLoad it will work. I have provided screenshots for configuration and code. Please ask me for details what information you would need before downvoting a valid question!

Comment: We can't tell from your description which case was run on the device, which on the simulator, nor can we tell how you have your device set.  And we can't tell which timezones "took", understanding that only certain timezone names are recognized by iOS.  You should log the `secondsFromGMT` value of the timezone object after you create it.  And make sure you only use a timezone name from `knownTimeZoneNames`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. Updated the device details. Swift is only avialable with xcode 6 and IOS8x and so thought its easy for developers to get it.  If certain time zones are recognized by IOS then it won't work for any setting. it works for one setting and doesnot for other

Comment: You're not being clear:  Which "setting" does it work for, and which not?

Comment: It works when my clock setting on my device is set to automatic but won't work when its manually set. Screenshot is added for the setting where i see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out the issue.
Asia/Hong_Kong never had a abbreviation under NSTimeZone and so it was coming as Null. Because it was Null the code used to take the default time from the device.
Interestingly the code didn't throw error.
Changing the code to this has worked.

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: eachZone)!
```

Comment: More or less what I said.

Comment: Not really. Known time zone names provided by Apple have "Asia/Hong_Kong" in it. Even then it don't have abbreviation. To make things simpler i had extracted those 2 names from knownTimeZoneNames

Comment: On which platform?  Simulator and device are not necessarily the same there.